# String Variable Functions Php

Tags: php, string, variables, tags, addition

My English is not good But I think you will understand.
I am taking data with cURL metods.

I have one string variable. This is.

```
$contents = 300 g of cooled marzipan raw material approx 35 g of powdered sugar for molding 200 g of dark chocolate couverture 50 skinned half almond kernels
```

I want a function or method to add a tag before each number(300,35,200,50)
I want to edit it in this way.

```
$contents = <li>300 g of cooled marzipan raw material approx</li><li>35 g of powdered sugar for molding</li><li>200 g of dark chocolate couverture </li><li>50 skinned half almond kernels
```

Find the numbers of the variable and add the list tag before number.
Warning : I try many function but the result was that. i don't want this. The numbers will take on a whole (300,50,....)

```
 $contents = </li><li>3</li><li>0</li><li>0 g of cooled marzipan raw material approx</li><li>3</li><li>5 g of powdered sugar for molding</li><li>2</li><li>0</li><li>0 g of dark chocolate couverture </li><li>5</li><li>0 skinned half almond kernels
```

and this content everytime changing. I tried too many function. I think the answer is preg_replace.But I never use this method.

And second problem ;

Again i have a string variable

```
$contentImg = "<img src="//i.hurimg.com/i/hurriyet/75/194x110/57bbf91967b0a930747c6900.jpg" data-src="//i.hurimg.com/i/hurriyet/75/194x110/594fa5cd18c7732b9c99c4ca.jpg" alt="Türk Malı yeni bölüm ne zaman Star Tv yayın akışında olacak" class="lazy " />"
```

i want change this variable. I want do this from $contentImg variable.

```
 $contentImg = "<img src="//i.hurimg.com/i/hurriyet/75/194x110/594fa5cd18c7732b9c99c4ca.jpg" alt="Star Tv yayın akısında olacak" class="lazy " />"
```

As a result,I want to delete

> src="//i.hurimg.com/i/hurriyet/75/194x110/57bbf91967b0a930747c6900.jpg" data-

this line from $contentImg variable or diffrent variable . 
Url difference should not affect the situation.
Even if it is different must delete that line. 
I hope I was able to express myself =) 
Thanks

Comment: Go through a tutorial on "Regular expressions" also known as regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to do that I use explode and is_numeric and then substr functions

```
    <?php
        $contents = "300 g of cooled marzipan raw material approx 35 g of powdered sugar for molding 200 g of dark chocolate couverture 50 skinned half almond kernels";
        $newwords ="";
        $word= explode(" " , $contents);
        foreach ($word as $value) {
            if (is_numeric($value)){
                $newwords .="</li><li>"." ".$value;
            }
            else { 
                $newwords .=" ".$value;
            }
        }
$newwords=$newwords."<li>";
        $newwords=substr($newwords, 5);
        echo $newwords;
        ?>
```

For the second problem I don't know if that is what you want

```
<?php
$contentImg = "<img src=\"//i.hurimg.com/i/hurriyet/75/194x110/57bbf91967b0a930747c6900.jpg\" data-src=\"//i.hurimg.com/i/hurriyet/75/194x110/594fa5cd18c7732b9c99c4ca.jpg\" alt=\"Türk Malı yeni bölüm ne zaman Star Tv yayın akışında olacak\" class=\"lazy \" />";
$myvariable=explode("src=\"",$contentImg);
 $newsrc= "i.hurimg.com/i/hurriyet/75/194x110/594fa5cd18c7732b9c99c4ca.jpg";
echo $myvariable["0"]."src=\"".$newsrc."\" alt=\"Star Tv yayın akısında olacak\" class=\"lazy \" />";
?>
```

Comment: I trying that now . Thank You =) @osama

Comment: just one think add </li> after the loop to the $newwords